# AWS Hook-EnactAppDeploy: Command hooks failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, asp.net

DevOps Pipeline fails to deploy web application archive to AWS ElasticBeanstalk instance with the following error in cfn-init.log:

```
    2019-04-16 19:18:35,822 [ERROR] Command hooks (HooksExecutor.exe appdeploy\enact) failed
2019-04-16 19:18:35,822 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of Hook-EnactAppDeploy: Command hooks failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 544, in run_config
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 138, in run_commands
  File "cfnbootstrap\command_tool.pyc", line 117, in apply
ToolError: Command hooks failed
```

Any idea what's causing this error? I don't even know where to begin on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this one on my own. Looks like my files were still being used by the app and this was causing the error. Switching to an immutable deployment in the ElasticBeanstalk settings solved this issue.

Comment: 4 years later and the issue can still occur as I am now facing it as well. Unfortunately, changing the deployment policy from "All at once" to "Immutable" did not fix it for me :(